# Open source self-hosted software for replacing Twitter in 2022

Tags: open-source, web-apps, progressive-web-application

Is there any open source software that exists self-hosted which can replace any modern social networking site eg. Twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Mastodon](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon) if you want to have your own instance which can optionally connect to the federated network of other Mastodon instances.
- [Nitter](https://github.com/zedeus/nitter) if you want to access the Twitter content via your own frontend.

Comment: Mastodon is a server. will it give all the features of Twitter? what do we need to add on Mastodon to stop spreading misleading information?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).